# How can I pass a record to another table in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I checked a checkbox in 1st table that entire row should be display in second table. Here I did this with hard coded but I need to do this as a dynamic way.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        itemID: 'BR063',
        itemValue: '145154'
    }, {
        itemID: 'BR053',
        itemValue: '145154'
    }];
 $scope.selectedItems = [];
  
 $scope.addRec = function(result, i){
    if(result == true){
     
     $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i]);
    }
    else{ 
     $scope.selectedItems.pop();
    }
 }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app = 'myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<h1>Select Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in items">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="itsVal" ng-change = "addRec(itsVal, $index+1)";/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<h1>Selected Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in selectedItems">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: Grab the index of row you clicked and update the model that is associated with grid #2.

Comment: I hope my answer below helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need.

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
     $scope.items = [{
   itemID: 'BR064',
   itemValue: '145154'
  }, {
   itemID: 'BR065',
   itemValue: '145155'
  },
  {
   itemID: 'BR066',
   itemValue: '145156'
  },
  {
   itemID: 'BR067',
   itemValue: '145157'
  },
  {
   itemID: 'BR068',
   itemValue: '145158'
  }];
  $scope.selectedItems = [];
     
  $scope.addRec = function(result, x){
      if(result == true){
    $scope.selectedItems.push(x);
   } else {
    if($scope.selectedItems.length){
    let idx = 0;
    $scope.selectedItems.find(function(element, i) {
           if(element.itemValue === x.itemValue){
         idx = i;
     }
    });
    $scope.selectedItems.splice(idx, 1);
   }
     }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app = 'myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<h1>Select Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in items">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="itsVal" ng-change = "addRec(itsVal, x)";/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<h1>Selected Rows</h1>
<table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
<tr>
<th class="text-center">Index</th>
<th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
<th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
<th class="text-center">Select</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in selectedItems">
<td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"  /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: This is wrong - clue here `$scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i-1]);` you cannot just remove the last added, try selecting 1, then 2, then unselect 1, then select it again

Comment: how can i remove selected

Comment: Instead of `.pop()` method, get the id which is `i` and use `.splice()` method of JavaScript to remove a particular element.

Comment: how can i use splice for perticular item

Comment: Updated the code, note that i am passing the value of model `x` instead of index now.

Answer (score 1):

change the addRec function to

```
$scope.addRec = function(result, i){
      if(result == true){

         $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i]);
      }
      else{ 
          $scope.selectedItems.pop();
      }
}
```

Comment: just now i updated with your code , but if i selected 2nd record then its pushing emty row

Comment: $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.items[i-1]) ; change the line to this code. reduce the index by 1 and push the code

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Send the object to function

**2-** Check existence in selected array

**3-** Remove or Add item to array

The answer will be this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    itemID: 'BR063',
    itemValue: '145154'
  }, {
    itemID: 'BR053',
    itemValue: '145154'
  }];
  $scope.selectedItems = [];

  $scope.addRec = function(itm) {
    let index = $scope.selectedItems.findIndex((iitt)=> {
      return itm.itemID == iitt.itemID;
    });
    if (index == -1) {
      $scope.selectedItems.push(itm);
    } else {
      $scope.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <h1>Select Rows</h1>
  <table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Index</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
      <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
      <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="itsVal" ng-change="addRec(x)" ;/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h1>Selected Rows</h1>
  <table style="width:50%" class="table-responsive table-bordered ">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Index</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Item Values</th>
      <th class="text-center">Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in selectedItems">
      <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemID}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{x.itemValue}}</td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
```